# Can we wait for another repo workflow to complete before trigger the workflow in github actions?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have three github repos `test`, `core` and `actual`. I want to trigger a workflow in `actual` repo when the `test` repo and `core` repo workflows are completed successfully. Both `test` and `core` repo workflows run parallelly. Is there any way to do this in github actions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I have had this issue and any existing published actions do not really satisfy the same situation you're in so I've made a couple of actions that facilitate this:

[`return-dispatch`](https://github.com/Codex-/return-dispatch)
This allows you to dispatch and get the run number needed to await completion.

[`await-remote-run`](https://github.com/Codex-/await-remote-run)
This awaits completion and provides a pass or fail etc.

Both have examples and documentation, hope this suits

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem possible, for non-interdependent workflows, especially for different repositories.

A workaround would be to use the [Wait On Check Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/wait-on-check) ([repo GitHub](https://github.com/lewagon/wait-on-check-action)), which allows for a job to wait, through [Checks API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#runs), for another to complete.

As mentioned in [issue 3](https://github.com/lewagon/wait-on-check-action/issues/3), it only supports jobs from *one* repository, so you might need to fork that action, and apply [this patch](https://github.com/kelu27/wait-on-check-action/commit/c1f750667217f02a70999e083fb3f7d9c0e7bac3) in order to support other repositories as well.